# Issue with google maps v3 and chrome 59

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hey I have updated my chrome and after this google maps on our website totally bugs out. Here is what it looks like. We have not changed our code in months and the map was working properly.

this is what we have found so far:
The map works properly when it is on a laptop screen. When moved to a larger screen it breaks as in the image below. when returned to the laptop screen upon refreshing it works again.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.28&key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&language=@lang"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue in the public issue tracker regarding rendering problems in Chrome 58+.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38211242

I would suggest reporting this problem there.